# problem with python inspect module-python

Tags: python

how to write a program to "identify the line number of the function call?"

python inspect module provides options to locate the line number but,

```
def di():
  return inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno
```

this python code prints the current line number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `inspect.stack()`?

```
def get_caller_lineno():
    frame, _, lineno, _, _, _ = inspect.stack()[1]
    return lineno
```

Comment: The file name is the second part of the tuple: `frame, filename, lineno, … = inspect.stack()[1]`

Answer (score 0):

I published a wrapper for inspect with simple stackframe addressing covering the stack frame by a single parameter `spos`:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysourceinfo/
- https://pythonhosted.org/pysourceinfo/

E.g.
`pysourceinfo.PySourceInfo.getCallerLinenumber(spos=1)`

where `spos=0` is the lib-function, `spos=1` is the caller, `spos=2` the caller-of-the-caller, etc.